# Gathering data at compile time using macros

Tags: rust, dioxus

I'm writing a rust macro that allows for definition of CSS styles in the global scope at compile time similar to Aphrodite in React. The problem is how to combine all the css into either a single string or to write all the classes to a file at compile time. Is there any nice way in which to do this or a work around to achieve something similar?

I have been able to build a hashmap of the css properties of a style at runtime and do checks on the CSS; allowing the definition of objects like this.

```rust
css_stylesheet! {
    button : {
        color: "red"
    },
}
```

However, once the map is created I don't know how to add it to either a global map or string. I am using the "phf" crate for compile time maps.

Comment: This is quite a problem, since macros only see the tokens they work at. A non-supported tricks is to have a `static` in the proc-macro crate and store all data there. This has worked in the past, however I don't know if it still works with incremental compilation, and it's definitely not guaranteed to work. There are other clever ways that may work, but I can't think of any on the top of my head.

Comment: One way to approach this is with a global filesystem cache that one macro writes to and a build system reads from. This is what I used in the collect-assets crate for dioxus: https://github.com/DioxusLabs/collect-assets